# Pull all data slices in one request in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I know Microsoft Azure API has a way to pull a data slice using a GET request. The api is here

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourcegroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/<DataFactoryName>/tables/<TableName>/sliceruns?start=<StartDateTime>&api-version=<Api-Version>
```

Problem is I have to manually specify the data factory, data set, and start time, what if I want to pull all logs for a start time for a particular resource group. I know I can do it if I list all data factories and sets and then loop through them. But then I'm calling an http request inside a nested for loop which seems like a really bad/expensive idea. I'm working on a logging web app using Kibana that's why I need all logs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported. This is due to the way that API routes are designed for Azure Resource Manager (ARM) services, which ADF is one of. The solution you mentioned, while not ideal, is the best available one.

A bit more: API routes for top-level resources (e.g. a data factory) will always contain a subscription ID and resource group name. Similarly, routes for child resources/APIs (e.g. datasets, slices, etc.) must contain the subscription ID, resource group name and the **top-level resource name**.

If there was such an API that let you list slices from any data factories in a resource group, this would have to be executed as a "fan-out" query. Since the data factories in the resource group can be in any region, ARM would have to send requests to each of the Data Factory resource providers (RPs) that has a data factory in the resource group, then aggregate and return the results to the caller; this is not supported by any of the Azure services.